# Word for in-house jargon

Tags: synonyms

If a word or phrase is used and has evolved its own meaning peculiar to a specific group, is this described as *jargon* or is there a closer semantic match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *jargon* usually has a meaning peculiar to a specific group. A synonym is *intalk*. Here's the Wiktionary definition for confirmation.

> [**jargon**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jargon)
>
> **Noun**
>
> **jargon** (*countable and uncountable*; *plural* **jargons**)
>
> 1. (*uncountable*) A technical terminology unique to a particular
>    subject.
> 2. (*countable*) Language characteristic of a particular group.
> 3. (*uncountable*) Speech or language that is incomprehensible or
>    unintelligible; gibberish.
>
> **Synonyms** (*language characteristic of a group*): argot, cant,
> intalk, slang vernacular

Comment: I like the intalk suggestion. Great word.

Answer (score 4):

The [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jargon) of jargon refers to the vocabulary of a specific group:

> the language, especially the vocabulary, peculiar to a particular trade, profession, or group

However, if the word or phrase developed to keep others out (that is, it was purposefully created as a kind of linguistic barrier) it might be classified as a [cant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cant_%28language%29):

> Cant is the jargon, argot or cryptolect of a group, often implying its use to exclude or mislead people outside the group

Comment: I think that sense of "cant" is hopelessly archaic today.

Answer (score 1):

On can also see **term of art** for some things like this.

> **term of art** NOUN
> A word or phrase that has a precise, specialized meaning within a particular field or profession.
> ‘public domain’ is a term of art in copyright law and you shouldn't throw it around if you don't know what it means

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/term_of_art)

Answer (score 1):

The word **vernacular** would work.